# GetAssetPreview always returns null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, thumbnails

I have a small unity editor script that gets asset previews from unity and saves them to a folder. It works well for my machine but it doesn't work on another machine that has the same project. 
Here is the code I use:

```
GameObject[] objs = Resources.LoadAll<GameObject>("");
foreach (GameObject obj in objs)
{
    Texture2D previewImage = null;
    while (previewImage == null)
    {
        previewImage = AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(obj);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(previewImage.name + ".png", previewImage.EncodeToPNG());
}
```

The code stays in an infinite loop where it says `previewImage == null`. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I have been struggling with the same issue and what seems to work really well for me is the following code:

```
AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(prefab), ImportAssetOptions.ForceUpdate);
```

This will cause a bit of lag for large asset databases, but not too much.

Another way of solving this issue is to use:

```
EditorUtility.SetDirty(prefab);
```

This however is sooo much slower...

Check both and see which one fits your needs, but I would go with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditorUtility.SetDirty(prefab);
```

Worked for me! Thanks!
For textures it returns whole atlas, but with 3d model worked good.
I needed a couple of hacks to prevent application failure:

1. Max tries counter.
2. Sprites dictionary for not calling SetDirty() every time.

   ```
    public static Texture2D GetPreviewForced(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        int instanceId = obj.GetInstanceID();

        if (_itemsPreviews.ContainsKey(obj))
        {
            return _itemsPreviews[obj];
        }
        else
        {
            if (Application.isPlaying)
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(obj);

            Texture2D result = AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(obj);
            int tries = 1000;
            while (AssetPreview.IsLoadingAssetPreview(instanceId) && tries > 0)
            {
                tries--;
            }

            if (tries != 0)
                _itemsPreviews.Add(obj, result);
            return result;
        }
    }
   ```